# Accessing Google Bookmarks server side with PHP

Tags: php, api, bookmarks

I used to access my Google Bookmarks, server side with this PHP code:

```
$curlObj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=rss");
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "whatever@googlemail.com:mypassword");
curl_setopt ($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curlObj);
echo $response;
curl_close($curlObj);
```

Formerly, with the code above, I would have seen an XML feed.

Now it shows "302 Your document has moved. Click Here".
The link takes me to a login page.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

such authorization is no longer working. you need auth via `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin` and after get `https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=rss`

example:

```
<?
$USERNAME = 'aaa';
$PASSWORD = 'bbb';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=bookmarks&continue=http://www.google.com/bookmarks');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$formFields = getFormFields($data); // my code to get form fields, ask if you want it

$formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
$formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

$post_string = '';
foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// echo var_dump($info);
if ($info['url']=="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth")
    {
      die("Login failed");
    var_dump($result);
 } else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=rss');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
}

function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
```